# AWS SQS - inserting a single message but can only fetch a list?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-sqs

I'm using .Net core to access an SQS queue and get a message from that queue.

Everything works fine.

For inserting a  message :

```
 var sendMessageRequest = new SendMessageRequest();
 sendMessageRequest.QueueUrl = queueName;
 sendMessageRequest.MessageBody = message;
 sqs.SendMessage(sendMessageRequest);
```

Notice that I can only insert a single message :

[image]

However when I was looking at the `ReceieveMessage` method :

```
 public static void GetMessage(AmazonSQSClient sqs , string queueName  )
        {
            var receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest { QueueUrl = queueName };
            var receiveMessageResponse = sqs.ReceiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest);
```

I've noticed that I can only get a list :

[image]

**Question:**

I  don't understand how come I can insert a single message , but read a list of messages ?

Even if I have many messages in my queue , this code ^ only fetches one message  :

[image]

Where I  have 6 messages :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to send multiple messages in a single API call, there is `SendMessageBatch` documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SQS/MSQSSendMessageBatchStringList!SendMessageBatchRequestEntry!.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SQS/MSQSSendMessageBatchSendMessageBatchRequest.html).

If you want to receive only a single message per request, you would set `ReceiveMessageRequest.MaxNumberOfMessages` to `1`.

Comment: Thanks , but How come AWS gives me only 1 message , while I have 5 in queue  (`while  I'm explicitly  asking  for 5`)? https://i.imgur.com/n3XVtGa.jpg

Comment: You can't explicitly ask SQS for 5. You are most likely setting the **Max** messages to 5, but that doesn't guarantee you will get 5, it just guarantees you will never get more than 5. What are you setting `WaitTimeSeconds` to? If that is very low it may be affecting how SQS is bundling up messages for you.

Comment: Got it. it's AWS that determines how much to fetch up to this max boundry.

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes, but you should *always* set `WaitTimeSeconds` to 20 unless you have a specific reason not to.  Not setting this at all will increase your chances of getting fewer messages or even 0 messages, and setting it does not cause SQS to actually wait that long unless there really are no messages available -- in which case, it will wait that long and then return 0, or will return the next message to arrive immediately upon its arrival.  This dramatically reduces operational costs and improves overall performance and should have been the default behavior.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Can I set maxNumberOfMessages to 100  and receiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds to 20. Does it guarantee that I will receive 100 messages in 20 seconds if its available? I read in the documentation that SQS always send a max of 10 messages in a single batch call. Can you please help to understand this

Comment: @RoyalTiger the service will not return more than 10 messages per poll.  WaitTimeSeconds is how long a poll request will be suspended by the service when waiting for at least one message to arrive at an empty queue so that it can return it to you.